# Trouble at my workplace

Tags: software-engineering

I was given a promotion at work and most of my colleagues are grumbling since I'm way younger and more experienced.

How should I approach this ?

Comment: Do you mean "less experienced"? Grumbling about someone more experienced being promoted is... odd.

Comment: I don't know whether they're jealous since I entered the company a year ago

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: does this promotion just mean you got a raise, or does it also mean that you are now a supervisor/leader/manger over  the older and more experienced employees?

Comment: I experienced the same atmosphere when I was recruited to move from a sister company and was announced to all an sundry by our MD as the best thing since sliced bread and sure it irritated a lot of people. I stayed there for 12 years and some people never came round as I got promoted often despite being 10-20 years younger than the other managers.

The only solution was to get on with proving you were as good as the MD said & sing your own praises through hard work and achievements. Good people will want to work with and for you and in time even the grumblers will give you grudging respect!

Comment: Why do you care if not everyone loves you?  Friendships are based on how you treat people!

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this problem by focusing on your work and do a very good job to prove that you truly deserve the promotion.

At the same time, keep a good work relationship with your older coworkers. Listen to their input, and respect their input at work. Be ready to help them if necessary. Try to get along well with them.